# SubTable SAP Service Layer

Tags: sapb1

How do I access objects within another object using the SAP B1 service layer?

Example: I have the following output, how do I access it using the service layer's "select" to select the fields "CardCode", "CardName" e "AddressName": {

```
 "odata.metadata": "https://sap:50000/b1s/v1/$metadata#BusinessPartners",<br>    
"value": ["odata.etag": "W/\"AC3478D69A3C81FA62E60F5C3696165A4E5E6AC4\"",
"CardCode": "C013925",
"CardName": "BUSINESS PARTNERS",
"BPAddresses": 
[
"AddressName": "FATURAMENTO",
"Street": "QUINTINO VARGAS",
"Block": "CENTRO"}
]
}
```

I tried everything in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to apply select to nested objects it will not work.
That's just not possible.
Instead you can use SQLQueries.